# Safari/Chrome browser not able to play videos more than 16 video on iPhone

Tags: safari, html5-video, mobile-safari

We have a mobile first website created using React.js and Onsen UI. The application has a screen of chapter listing and each chapter has many videos. On selecting any chapter from listing, we are showing video one by one using a carousel ( one video per carousel slides using HTML video tag ).

Some chapters may have more than 20 videos. All video are of type mp4 and size is around 40kb - 3MB.

On iPhone using Safari or Chrome browser, after a 16th video that means on 17th video, I am getting a black screen and slash through play button. There is no error or any warning on browser console.

Here is sample image of a slash through play button.

[image]

And once this black screen comes it will start appearing for all videos.

I have sample code, you can play video in any order, as soon as you click the 17th video it gives an error.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <style>
      .item {
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
      .carousel-control-next, .carousel-control-prev {
        background: red;
        margin: 15px;
        height: 40px;
      }
      .video {
        width: 100%;
      }
      .count {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 10;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h1>Video Issue!</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="item active">
            <video id="video-0" class="video" controls="" playsinline=""  >
              <source type="video/mp4" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathatesting/videos/video-0.mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <video id="video-1" class="video" controls="" playsinline="" >
              <source type="video/mp4" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathatesting/videos/video-1.mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <video id="video-2" class="video" controls="" playsinline="" >
              <source type="video/mp4" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathatesting/videos/video-2.mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <video id="video-3" class="video" controls="" playsinline="" >
              <source type="video/mp4" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathatesting/videos/video-3.mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <video id="video-4" class="video" controls="" playsinline="" >
              <source type="video/mp4" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathatesting/videos/video-4.mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <video id="video-5" class="video" controls="" playsinline="" >
              <source type="video/mp4" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathatesting/videos/video-5.mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <video id="video-6" class="video" controls="" playsinline="" >
              <source type="video/mp4" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathatesting/videos/video-6.mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <video id="video-7" class="video" controls="" playsinline="" >
              <source type="video/mp4" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathatesting/videos/video-7.mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <video id="video-8" class="video" controls="" playsinline="" >
              <source type="video/mp4" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathatesting/videos/video-8.mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <video id="video-9" class="video" controls="" playsinline="" >
              <source type="video/mp4" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathatesting/videos/video-9.mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <video id="video-10" class="video" controls="" playsinline="" >
              <source type="video/mp4" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathatesting/videos/video-10.mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <video id="video-11" class="video" controls="" playsinline="" >
              <source type="video/mp4" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathatesting/videos/video-11.mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <video id="video-12" class="video" controls="" playsinline="" >
              <source type="video/mp4" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathatesting/videos/video-12.mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <video id="video-13" class="video" controls="" playsinline="" >
              <source type="video/mp4" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathatesting/videos/video-13.mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <video id="video-14" class="video" controls="" playsinline="" >
              <source type="video/mp4" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathatesting/videos/video-14.mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <video id="video-15" class="video" controls="" playsinline="" >
              <source type="video/mp4" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathatesting/videos/video-15.mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <video id="video-16" class="video" controls="" playsinline="" >
              <source type="video/mp4" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathatesting/videos/video-16.mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <video id="video-17" class="video" controls="" playsinline="" >
              <source type="video/mp4" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathatesting/videos/video-17.mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <video id="video-18" class="video" controls="" playsinline="" >
              <source type="video/mp4" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathatesting/videos/video-18.mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <video id="video-19" class="video" controls="" playsinline="" >
              <source type="video/mp4" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathatesting/videos/video-19.mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <video id="video-20" class="video" controls="" playsinline="" >
              <source type="video/mp4" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathatesting/videos/video-20.mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is direct url to open on iphone browser, https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathatesting/videos/video-without-carousel.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the browser overloads since videos are cached try making it a bit dynamic by adding a bit javascript

Comment: Actually, I tested it with different size of the video, it only crashes (can play and show black screen ) when we try to play 17th video. No matter in which order you play, or after play if you remove video tag from DOM using js.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. The trick seems to be to replace the nested source tag without replacing the video tag as a whole. Remember to call .load() on the video element after you swap the source to trigger it to reload.

Comment: that could work, but in my case, I want to persist position of the previously played video.